# Cannot connect to FTP 7 server other than via localhost

Tags: windows-server-2008, ftp

I've just built an FTP site using the FTP 7 package on Windows Server 2008.  I've configured it to use IIS Manager Authentication following [this article](http://www.trainsignaltraining.com/windows-server-2008-ftp-user-authentication/2008-04-30/).  When at the console of the Windows Server 2008 machine, I can FTP to localhost, login using an account I created in the IIS Management tool, and get to a user isolated directory.  When I try to connect to the FTP site from any other computer, whether it is on the local network (trying ftp 10.1.10.2) or from a public computer (trying ftp ), I cannot even get to a login prompt.  Instead I get "ftp: connect :Connection timed out".  What might I need to configure on the FTP server so that at least a machine on the local network with no routers in between the client and server can connect?

Comment: When you say you can FTP to localhost, do you mean 127.0.0.1, or are you connecting to the 10.1.10.2 address locally?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a firewall problem to me.  Is windows firewall running on the machine?